# GPL with exception to use without publishing the source

Tags: gpl

I am using a GPL licensed library which stated clearly that it is OK to link to it in commercial projects without the need to publish your own source code (as an exception to the regular GPL that force you to publish the source along with your product).

Let us call this library with an modified GPL license "**Library A**". Now, there is another library (let us call it "**Library B**") that link with the **Library A**. The **Library B** itself is licensed under GPL but without that exception which allow you to keep the source closed.

My question is:

Is licensing the **Library B** without this exception too a legal action? I mean since the author(s) of **Library B** uses **Library A**, doesn't this force them to add the exception to their library too?

In other words, can link to **Library B** in my commercial product with the need to publish my source?

Comment: The short answer is no.  The library with the exception in its license does not give you a buffer against which you can link GPL'd libraries without triggering the copyleft provisions.  Were that the case, you could simply write your own shim to disable the GPL license.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some confusing terminology in there.

The GPL does not permit what you claim the library allowed you to do.

The LGPL (Lesser GPL, formerly Library GPL) does.

What it sounds like you are saying is that you have LibraryA that is LGPL, and LibraryB that is GPL, and you want to link BOTH of them to your commercial application without your commercial application contracting the GPL virus.

Sorry, Dave, you can't do that.  LibraryA allows it.  LibraryB says you have to GPL your source if you use it.

The original authors of LibraryB were OK using LibraryA, which was LGPL.  They played by the rules.  They **COULD HAVE** released LibraryB under LGPL, and they chose ***NOT*** to do so.  Rather, they chose to release LibraryB under the GPL, which requires users of LibraryB to release their code under GPL, including making source available, and you are also required to play by the rules.

Comment: The GPLv3 allows the copyright holder to grant extra permissions, such as freely linking against that library. In fact, the LGPLv3 is implemented using this extra permissions mechanism. Another common permission is the Classpath Exception in Java code. Extra permissions were also routinely granted under other GPL versions. So it is perfectly possible for Library A to be under GPL + sone exceptions, without actually being under the LGPL. Your remaining analysis is still correct.